# sortTestMethodsUsing doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, python-unittest

I try to order my tests but the problem is that the `test_add` will be first and I need that the `test_remove` will be first. I try to use `sortTestMethodsUsing` but I still get `test_add` as the first test.

```
import unittest


class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_remove(self):
        print("1")

    def test_add(self):
        print("2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    loader.sortTestMethodsUsing = None
    unittest.main(testLoader=loader)
```

Comment: The default ordering is alphabetical. I usually use names like: `test_001_remove, test_002_add, ...` to enforce a certain order

Comment: @schwobaseggl the problem is that I have many tests and sometimes I need to add another test to my tests and then I need to update the number of my tests for example `test_001_remove, test_002_add, ... test_097_add_number`

Comment: I see, you can add infixes like `test_003a, test_003b`. But mostly not all of those many tests will depend on order. Try to break it up in separate classes to keep em managable